# htaccess Redirect 301 redirects to wrong url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've created a bunch of 301 redirects in my .htaccess, for example

```
Redirect 301 / /de/
Redirect 301 /site_1/ https://www.new.com/de/company/site_1/
Redirect 301 /services/site_2/ https://www.new.com/de/services/site_1/
```

and so on.

When I enter

`www.old.com/site_1/` (wrong)

I get directed to

`https://www.new.com/de/site_1/` (services folder missing)

It seems that the parent folder is missing in the redirected URL. Same for all other sites that reside in folders.

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue by replacing Redirect with RedirectMatch directives.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I overlooked the first directive. Glad you resolved it. `Redirect` is prefix-matching, so your request gets caught by the first directive - that is no doubt what was causing your problem. I've put more information in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Redirect 301 / /de/
> Redirect 301 /site_1/ https://www.new.com/de/company/site_1/
> Redirect 301 /services/site_2/ https://www.new.com/de/services/site_1/
> ```

Since the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix-matching*, a request for `www.old.com/site_1/` would actually get caught by your first (most general) rule. And everything after the match (ie. `site_1/`) gets appended onto the end of the target URL (ie. `/de/`), so the resulting redirect becomes `/de/site_1/` (but not to `new.com` as you've stated?).

You could resolve this by reversing the directives, to have the most specific matches first. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /services/site_2/ https://www.new.com/de/services/site_1/
Redirect 301 /site_1/ https://www.new.com/de/company/site_1/
Redirect 301 / /de/
```

Or, as you mentioned in comments, use `RedirectMatch` instead - which is not prefix-matching and matches against a specific regex instead. Although you will still need to modify the pattern. Something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /de/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site_1/$ https://www.new.com/de/company/site_1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/services/site_2/$ https://www.new.com/de/services/site_1/
```

Although this now matches the exact URL, which may or may not be what you require.